# Is there ANY way to edit, or at least view a MobileMe gallery on iPad?

Tags: ipad, mobileme, photos

So I have a MobileMe account.  (Yes, I know that there are free alternatives; my wife hates change.)

So I post galleries of photos on MobileMe, and then **from a computer** I can either:

- Log in to my MobileMe account as the owner, where I can see my gallery, and edit it (delete photos, etc.)
- Go to the public, shared, gallery url, which allows me to view or download pics, but not edit the gallery, just like the folks I share the link with can.

But **from my iPad,** I can't really do either:

- If I try to go to login to MobileMe (at me.com), the MobileMe site sees that I'm on a mobile device, and won't open, routing me instead to the app store to get the mobileme gallery app, which is for the iphone, and scales pictures in a totally ridiculous way on the ipad.  There is no option to open the "normal" full website.
- If I try to go to the shared gallery url from my iPad, I can see the pics, but the thumbnails on the side use some kind of web tech that the iPad doesn't have, so I cant scroll.  I can only open the pics from the thumbnails that fit onto the ipad screen.  (Yes, I tried two finger scrolling.)

Any ideas?

Comment: I, too have experienced these problems and am very disappointed with it. I have just purchased a year of subscription and am having serious doubts. The whole idea was to use a system that was universal. Now having paid over £600 for an iPad I find that I can't actually carry out the basics on MobileMe. I do hope someone can come up with an intelligent answer to our dilemma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MobileMe Gallery App](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mobileme-gallery/id350223710?mt=8) is now an universal app.

Answer (score 4):

[MobileMe Gallery App for iPhone, iPod, and iPad](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mobileme-gallery/id350223710?mt=8)

Comment: This is the gallery app I referenced in the question- despite the name of the app, it is not a universal app, and the ipad version just scales up the iphone or runs in a tiny window.